# Start and stop simple clock on button push

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple webpage:

```
<html>
  <body>
    When button has value of "Start Clock" and button is pushed:
      <li>The clock information is shown in the textfield</li>
      <li>The value of the button changes to "Stop Clock"</li>
    When the button has the value "Stop Clock" and button is pushed
      <li>The clock information stops in the textfied</li>
      <li>The button value changes to "Start Clock"</li>

    <input type="text" id="clocktext"/>
    <input type="button" id="clockb" value="Start Clock"/> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also have a script file:

```
function myclock() { 
    var date = new Date(); // Get the current date/time
    var hour = date.getHours(); // Save hours
    var min = date.getMinutes(); // Save minutes
    var sec = date.getSeconds(); // Save seconds
    formathour = format(hour); // Format hours
    formatmin = format(min); // Format minutes
    formatsec = format(sec); // Format seconds
    timeout = setTimeout("myclock()", 1000); 
}

function format(x) {
    if (x < 10) x = "0" + x;
    return x;
}

$("#clockb").click(function () {
    var c = setInterval(setTheTime(), 1000);
    if (this.value == "Start Clock") {
        $(this).prop('value', 'Stop Clock'); // Set button value to Stop Clock
    } else if (this.value == "Stop Clock") {
        $(this).prop('value', 'Start Clock');
            clearInterval(c);
    }
});

function setTheTime() {
    myclock();
    var curTime = formathour+":"+formatmin+":"+formatsec // Current time formatted
    $("#clocktext").prop('value', curTime);
}
```

I cannot get the clock to continually update when the button is pushed :/

I feel like I'm over complicating this and its very annoying.

Any insight would be helpful as I am very new to jQuery and js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code: http://jsfiddle.net/hUYZv/1/

Your error was in incorrect usage of setInterval. It should be:

```
var c = setInterval(setTheTime, 1000);
```

You want to provide a refference to the function not the result of its execution (as would be if you write `setTheTime()`);

Comment: What a simple mistake! I thank you for that. I still need to get the clock to stop updating when the button is clicked again

Comment: Ahh looking at your updates I figured out the problem. I had `var c = setInterval(setTheTime, 1000);` and I should have had `c = setInterval(setTheTime, 1000);`

I needed to have `c` declared globally so it could be accessed outside of the `if` statement it was in. 

Thank you so much =]

Comment: Yes because by the moment of the second click you don't have `c` available inside the scope because of the nature of closures.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.click on the span

```
<span id="clock" style="background-color:#9CC;float:right" onclick="updateClock();">&nbsp;</span>
<script type="text/javascript">

function updateClock ( )
{
var currentTime = new Date ( );

var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );
var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );

// Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros, if required
currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

  // Choose either "AM" or "PM" as appropriate
var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";

  // Convert the hours component to 12-hour format if needed
currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;

// Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
//currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;

// Compose the string for display
var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " "   + timeOfDay;

// Update the time display
document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTimeString;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I read over the site that had that code earlier on. My time is correctly formatted right now thanks. I'm just trying to get the clock to _stop_ updating when I click the button a second time

Comment: You can use the function also for a button onclick function. If it is useful to you then you can simply accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing one of two things:

- Either you didn't include the jquery lib inside your html file
- Either you didn't put your function inside a document.ready.

You should wrap two of your functions like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function setTheTime() {
    myclock();
    var curTime = formathour+":"+formatmin+":"+formatsec // Current time formatted
    $("#clocktext").prop('value', curTime);
}

$("#clockb").attr("onclick", "").click(function () {
    var c = setInterval(setTheTime(), 1000);
    if (this.value == "Start Clock") {
        $(this).prop('value', 'Stop Clock'); // Set button value to Stop Clock
    } else if (this.value == "Stop Clock") {
        $(this).prop('value', 'Start Clock');
            clearInterval(c);
    }
});
```

You can see a working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/T47ME/